# Can anybody suggest a good Debugging package for PHP?

Tags: php, debugging

I use firebug and smarty so i get good debugging data from that but i'd like to see my database query times and page processing times as well.

Answer (score 3):

Xdebug is very good. It works very well in combination with Netbeans IDE for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great package to relay data to firebug:

http://www.firephp.org

Answer (score 1):

[xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) is awesome, because it lets you step through code inspecting variables as you go.

It also lets you do profiling (dumps callgrind files into a directory of your choosing, describing in very detailed fashion what happened how many times, when, and how long everything took)

To take full advantage of xdebug, you need a good IDE, i suggest [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/), but you can use any one of the major packages nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

As linked many times by others, FirePHP and Xdebug are awesome...

But you also asked about page render times and query times.

Unless you're already using a framework that collects this data for you, you're going to need to collect it and set up reporting for it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging PHP Code on Windows with Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 => http://www.jcxsoftware.com